Mocking assignment of function to val with Mockito
I assign a function to a value depending on a flag similar to:
class Operations(classA: ClassA, classB: ClassB, enabled) {
    val func: () => String = if (enabled) 
        classA.doSomething 
    else 
        classB.doSomething

    func()
}

My actual application is complex so I've has to simplify it here with an example.
I've tried mocking this with something similar to:
val aMock = mock[ClassA]
val bMock = mock[ClassB]

when(aMock.doSomething(any())) thenReturn "something-a"
when(bMock.doSomething(any())) thenReturn "something-b"

new Operations(aMock, bMock, true)


It seems to me that doSomething from either classA or classB the function is not the mocked value. The code inside doSomething is running when I expect it to be mocked.
How would I mock the classes so that func remains the mocked value rather than the real implementation?
I'm new to scala and mockito so appreciate any guidance. I'm locked to Mockito 3.0 and Scala 2.13

Can you provide a reproduction scenario? What makes you think the mocks are not used?
